# Many issues "(servicename) could not be found"

Tags: centos, rhel, services, systemctl, systemd-unit

I've got issue in recently installed RHEL9.2.

When looking at `systemctl status -all` I've got no failed units, but i see many red notices about missing services somehow inserted into middle of regular systemctl lines:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-07-20 08:46:54 CEST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 953 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 48947)
     Memory: 13.2M
        CPU: 87ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─953 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Jul 20 08:46:54 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835614.4095] device (lo): Activation: succe>
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1875] device (ens192): state change:>
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1887] policy: set 'ens192' (ens192) >
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1928] device (ens192): state change:>
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1948] device (ens192): state change:>
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1950] device (ens192): state change:>
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1954] manager: NetworkManager state >
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1958] device (ens192): Activation: s>
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <info>  [1689835615.1970] manager: NetworkManager state >
Jul 20 08:46:55 hostname.fqdn NetworkManager[953]: <infUnit ntpd.service could not be found.
Unit ntpdate.service could not be found.
Unit plymouth-quit-wait.service could not be found.
Unit plymouth-start.service could not be found.
o>  [1689835615.1974] manager: startup complete
```

or another one:

```
○ initrd-udevadm-cleanup-db.service - Cleanup udev Database
Jul 20 08:46:48 hostname.fqdn systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup udev Database...
Jul 20 08:46:48 hostname.fqdn systemd[1]: initrd-udevadm-cleanup-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 20 08:46:48 hostname.fqdn systemd[1]: Finished CleanupUnit ip6tables.service could not be found.
Unit ipset.service could not be found.
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
 udev Database.
```

or another:

```
○ modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/modprobe@.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2023-07-20 08:46:50 CEST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:modpUnit network.service could not be found.
robe(8)
    Process: 705 ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe -abq drm (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 705 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 38ms
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you either didn't properly install it on a bare-metal machine OR that that version is bugged, because those services should be installed by default if those service units try to activate the missing ones.

Comment: Like I said, it was installed from official RHEL DVD with no errors. Official support confirmed issu.  Problem appears also in other linux distos with systemd - but only when instalation is very minimal. It appears little different in RHEL 8, errors appers after pgup/pgdown. Strange error that I saw many times before and finally access to official redhat support to ask :) First support line also was confused what the hell that was, even more confused when showed me session where support consultant created ssh session to their test/demo rhel 9 and found out, that he has same issue :)

Comment: Even major distros have bugs in their configurations, that it is an official release from them doesn't mean they are bug free lol

Answer (score 0):

Accually, I've created ticket for that issue in RHEL support, on their VMs they've got same issues, and they answered me, that those messages are "not revelant" and i should use systemctl status -all with `2>/dev/null` :)

However it's strange for me, that was their offical support answear for that issue...

> It means that you either didn't properly install it on a bare-metal machine OR that that version is bugged

It was correctly installed from official DVD, later updated to current version, however that's text-only minimal setup without GUI or almost anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/452208)

Answer (score 0):

Some service files can have dependencies to other services that might not be installed in a particular system configuration. For example. `blk-availability.service` is configured to run

```
After=iscsi-shutdown.service iscsi.service iscsid.service fcoe.service rbdmap.service
```

But if you don't have iSCSI, FCoE or RBD subsystems installed, none of the listed services will be present. Normally, this is harmless.

In RHEL 9.2 (and also in Debian 12 - both using systemd version 252), if you use `systemctl status -all`, each such missing unit will be reported with a `Unit <name> could not be found.` message to the standard error output. Unfortunately, the errors are not synced with the lines of the status report in the standard output stream, so they will interrupt the status report lines in the way you are experiencing.

This is clearly not how it is supposed to work, so it is a bug; however, since it is easily worked around with adding a `2>/dev/null` redirection to the command, it probably qualifies as a "minor nuisance only".

Since it appears both in RHEL and Debian, it is probably an upstream issue.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything :) I've found it also in current systemd based gentoo, which I test-installed recently :)

Comment: It's most likely an "upstream feature" to help fix downstream to properly configure stuff, which ofcourse is NOT how things are meant to be done... Those services, when installed, should add their own "After=" entry as a drop-in to the respective service, and thus not be added by default by those services when the other services are not installed... UNFORTUNATELY the community is still struggling with proper systemd configurtions, which "helping" them is actually counter productive in these cases because they will just NOT do the proper thing them self as it is done upstream already for them.